# SQL Queries on Access DB return null or empty results using mdbtools

Tags: php, ms-access, unixodbc, mdbtools

If I use any condition apart from `SELECT *` whilst querying an Access DB with ODBC I get the following error: `No tuples available at this result index`

Any ideas ? Here's the particular GROUP BY query:

```
$result = odbc_exec($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY MyColumn");
odbc_result_all($result);
```

**EDIT**

After running the query directly from mdbtools' command line tool, I get the following:

```
Error at Line : syntax error near GROUP
```

Comment: That is invalid MS Access SQL, you cannot group by fields selected with *.

Comment: Hmm, SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable GROUP BY MyColumn returns the same error though....

Comment: I do not think that is an MS Access error, did you see http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/ms-access-odbc-result-all-403027.html ?

Comment: Updated the description after discovering the mdbtools error...

Comment: Did you use * when testing with mdbtools?

Comment: Did you use the same field for both group by and select? It does not give a syntax error in Access, but it does give an error, which a simple `select mycolumn from mytable group by mycolumn` does not.

Comment: yep, used the same field. Also, a WHERE clause only works on integers. i.e. if you use Strings (even with the single quotes), it returns no result. I think the mdbtools library is buggy.

Comment: You might like to change your question title, because it does not seem to be relevant any longer. It might help get an answer.